# About how to link Quicktime.framework with libvidcap

Tags: c, macos, quicktime

I am tring to capture video using libvidcap in mac
I got the following errors while  installing libvidcap:

```
quicktime/sg_manager.c:73: error: 'struct sg_source' has no member named 'channel'
quicktime/sg_manager.c:74: error: 'sgDeviceListIncludeInputs' undeclared (first use in this function)
quicktime/sg_manager.c:75: error: 'device_list' undeclared (first use in this function)
quicktime/sg_manager.c:82: error: 'dlr' undeclared (first use in this function)
quicktime/sg_manager.c:103: error: 'SGDeviceInputListPtr' undeclared (first use in this function)
quicktime/sg_manager.c:103: error: expected ';' before 'ilr'
quicktime/sg_manager.c:109: error: 'ilr' undeclared (first use in this function)
quicktime/sg_manager.c:128: warning: implicit declaration of function 'SGDisposeDeviceList'
quicktime/sg_manager.c:128: error: 'struct sg_source' has no member named 'grabber'
```

I added the `QuickTime/QuickTimeComponents.h` header in my source, but this did not solve the problem. What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

./configure CFLAGS="-arch i386" LDFLAGS="-arch i386"